# listview and datapager problem

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-4.0, datapager

```
<asp:ListView runat="Server" ID="lvMain" DataKeyNames="HelpId" DataSourceID="objDsMain">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="5">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="CurrentPage" NumericButtonCssClass="PageNumbers"
                        NextPreviousButtonCssClass="PageNumbers" NextPageText=" > " PreviousPageText=" < " />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
             // obvious formatting here
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Pager result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

Expected something like:

```
< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... >
```

Why isn't the pager using the properties i specified? Even in specify a dropdown in the datapager's template it wont show. Using an ObjectDataSource btw.

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you need to set `ShowNextPageButton` and `ShowPreviousPageButton` properties of `NumericPagerField` to `true`

i.e.

```
<asp:NumericPagerField ... ShowNextPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="True" />
```